# C++ Place an image on top of another image in a certain location

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm looking for a way to place on image on top of another image at a set location.

I have been able to place images on top of each other using `cv::addWeighted` but when I searched for this particular problem, there wasn't any posts that I could find relating to `C++`.

**Quick Example:**

**`200x200` Red Square &  `100x100` Blue Square**

[image] **&** [image]

**Blue Square on the Red Square at `70x70` (From top left corner Pixel of Blue Square)**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a Mat that points to a rectangular region of the original image and copy the blue image to that:

```cpp
cv::Mat bigImage = cv::imread("redSquare.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::Mat lilImage = cv::imread("blueSquare.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

cv::Mat insetImage(bigImage, cv::Rect(70, 70, 100, 100));
lilImage.copyTo(insetImage);
    
cv::imshow("Overlay Image", bigImage);
```

Comment: //For place image at location Point(70,70) ;  smallImg.copyTo(BigImage(cv::Rect(10, 10, smallImg.cols, smallImg.rows))); this image

Comment: @MilindMorey why Rect(10, 10, ...) for Point(70,70)? How did you find 10?

Comment: @MilindMorey Your oneliner worked for me, while the answers did not.

Comment: @George Can you tell us what did and didn't work? Both should create an image, the only difference being the location of the smaller image inside the bigger one. And of course in your own code you should replace the hardcoded values with appropriate variables.

Answer (score 4):

Building from [beaker answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398615/2436175), and generalizing to any input images size, with some error checking:

```
cv::Mat bigImage = cv::imread("redSquare.png", -1);
const cv::Mat smallImage = cv::imread("blueSquare.png", -1);

const int x = 70;
const int y = 70;
cv::Mat destRoi;
try {
    destRoi = bigImage(cv::Rect(x, y, smallImage.cols, smallImage.rows));
}  catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "Trying to create roi out of image boundaries" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
smallImage.copyTo(destRoi);

cv::imshow("Overlay Image", bigImage);
```

Check [cv::Mat::operator()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6)

Note: Probably this will still fail if the 2 images have different formats, e.g. if one is color and the other grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested explicit algorithm:

1 - Read two images. E.g., *bottom.ppm, top.ppm*,
2 - Read the location for overlay. E.g., *let the wanted top-left corner of "top.ppm" on "bottom.ppm" be (x,y) where 0 < x < bottom.height() and 0 < y < bottom.width()*,
3 - Finally, nested loop on the top image to modify the bottom image pixel by pixel:

```
for(int i=0; i<top.height(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<top.width(), j++) {
        bottom(x+i, y+j) = top(i,j);
    }
}
```

return bottom image.

Comment: You should specify that what you provided is pseudocode.