# OpenCV C++ how to combine two image and save as one with position

Tags: c++, opencv

if i have 2 PNG images, i want to combine these two image and dump as one image, but I want to set the position where the images will be drawn,
Is this possible in OpenCV in C++?

example, first image will display in 0,0 (top left), and the second image which is smaller will be drawn at 50,50 and dump the result as a single image.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d98/tutorial_mat_operations.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395836/c-place-an-image-on-top-of-another-image-in-a-certain-location/29398615#29398615